# Stripping trailing zeroes from a floating pointer number, using a regex

Tags: regex, floating-point, pcre, strip

Given inputs such as:

```
123000
-123000
1.230000000
123.4000000
-123.4000000
123.0
```

Is there a regex that will match the non-trailing zero part, correspondingly giving the captures as follows?:

```
123000
-123000
1.23
123.4
-123.4
123.0
```

Comment: Any feedback on why this was down voted as a question?

Answer (score 1):

For your example data you could match one or more digits, a dot followed by zero or more times a digit `\d+\.[0-9]*` which is greedy and will match until the end of the line followed by matching a digit `[1-9]` to make sure that a value like 123.0 is not matched.

Then use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match. Anything that was consumed is no longer part of the match. Then match possible zeroes that you want to remove using `0*` and replace those with an empty string.

[`\d+\.[0-9]*[1-9]\K0*`](https://regex101.com/r/cG1ZBq/1)

Answer (score 1):

A possible candidate is

```
(?!00+)([+-]?\d+(\.\d?)?)(0*[1-9])*
```

as you can test in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZWc05Y/2).

The first group is a negative lookahead that prevents to select a matching string composed only of two or more zeros (`00000` or the trailing strings will be matched)

The second group matches an optional sign, followed by one or more digits, optionally followed by a literal dot and optionally a digit (the first digit after the decimal point can be zero, as you post in your example), then follows a group of 0 or more groups of digits from the set `[1-9]` separated by a group of zeros (this warrants that the number terminates at a nonzero digit)

Finally, you need to get the second group, which delimits the substring in which you have interest.  See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZWc05Y/2) for details.

## Update

forcing the negative lookahead to be at a non word boundary at the left, it doesn't match the final zero of a chain as a new number (contiguous numbers must be different words) leading to this new regular expression:

```
(?!\B00+)([+-]?\d+(\.\d?)?)(0*[1-9])*
```

as can be seen in [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/ZWc05Y/4)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is: `^(-?\d+(?:\.\d+?[1-9]*)?)0*$`

- `(` capturing group

  - `-?` optional -
  - `\d+` one or more digits
  - `(?:` non-capturing group

    - `\.\d+?` . followed by one or more digits (non-greedy)
    - `[1-9]*` zero or more non-zero digits
  - `)?` optionally match group
- `)`
- `0*` zero or more zeroes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple regex:

```
(\.[^0]+)0+ 

and replace with \1
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AXu1Wl/1)

Note: This will match all the `0`s after a decimal point (dot), but not the one immediately after decimal point

Edit: If you want required result in capture group 1, you can use the following:

```
([^.\s]+(?:\.[^0]+)?)0*
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AXu1Wl/2)

Comment: Sorry, but your demo doesn't work with the last value 123.0.  It matches it as two matches, not one.  It also matches `123.ASBDFDD0000` as a number... and it isn't

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a dozen ways to do it. I'd try

```
-?(\d+(?:\.[1-9]\d*?)?)0*$
```

Comment: That fails with e.g. "123.04", since [1-9] doesn't match the 0 after the decimal point.

Comment: You're right. I should have used something like -?\d+(?:\.\d(?:\d*[1-9])?)?. It doesn't matter what the first digit after the decimal is as long as it it only matches an optional string of digits ending with a positive number afterwards.